# Where does Dashlane store it's passwords data file?

Tags: backup, passwords, automation, password-management, dashlane

Where does [Dashlane](https://www.dashlane.com/), the popular password manager, store it's password file/files?

I am interested in automating a personal version control or backup of my passwords. Since automation is the goal, [exporting a backup is not an option](https://csdashlane.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202625092-How-to-export-or-back-up-your-Dashlane-account). Rather, I'd either like to backup just the password file or, if necessary, the entire application state. This backup would have to be able to be restored on any platform (minimum desktops).

1Password, for example, allows you to choose a location to store your password file and even encourage you store it in a synced folder such as Dropbox.

Answer (score 3):

On Mac, Dashlane stores its information at:

```
~/Library/Containers/com.dashlane.Dashlane
```

I have a line in my .bash_profile that looks like this:

```
cp -a Library/Containers/com.dashlane.Dashlane ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/
```

That copies my dashlane profile to iCloud every time I log in or open a command prompt.

Comment: Does this still work for you? What version of Dashlane are you on?

Comment: On my Mac (macOS 10.12.4), running Dashlane 4.7.0, there's no such file as
~/Library/Containers/com.dashlane.Dashlane
Nothing from Dashlane at all in the Containers folder.

Comment: This answer is outdated. Please see https://superuser.com/a/1379331/1004383

Answer (score 2):

The files are AES-encrypted and are stored locally, then synced with Dashlane servers upon login for synchronization purposes.

#### user's password data and files

> Any stored data is always encrypted into an indecipherable string of random letters, numbers, and symbols, which **is stored locally and also on Dashlane servers** for synchronization purposes. However, for your protection, as well as our own, we never store your Master Password or any of its derivatives on our servers at any time.

<sup>Source: [Dashlane’s Patented Security Architecture](https://blog.dashlane.com/dashlane-patented-security-architecture/)</sup>

> In the folders contained AES-encrypted files that contained passwords
>   and login info, sharing rights details, purchase histories, and more. These
>   **files are synced with Dashlane servers upon login** (provided there is internet access). In particular, we found that the file `localSettings.aes` contains the device authentication. Note that this device authentication is NOT tied to the computer itself; for example, if this folder was copied onto another computer, that computer could log into the account without prior verification.

<sup>Source: [Security Analysis of Dashlane (May 2016)](https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.857/2016/files/25.pdf)</sup>

Location on macOS:

```
$ sudo lsof -p $(pgrep -d, Dashlane) | grep -w $USER/Library
/Users/USER/Library/Application Support/CloudDocs/session/containers/com.apple.Preview.plist
/Users/USER/Library/Saved Application State/com.dashlane.Dashlane.savedState/window_1.data
/Users/USER/Library/Saved Application State/com.dashlane.Dashlane.savedState/data.data
/Users/USER/Library/Saved Application State/com.dashlane.Dashlane.savedState/windows.plist
/Users/USER/Library/Caches/com.dashlane.Dashlane/Cache.db
/Users/USER/Library/Saved Application State/com.dashlane.Dashlane.savedState/window_9.data
/Users/USER/Library/Caches/com.dashlane.DashlaneAgent/Cache.db-shm
/Users/USER/Library/Caches/com.dashlane.DashlaneAgent/Cache.db
/Users/USER/Library/Caches/com.dashlane.DashlaneAgent/Cache.db-wal
/Users/USER/Library/Caches/com.dashlane.DashlaneAgent/Cache.db-shm
/Users/USER/Library/Caches/com.dashlane.DashlanePluginService/Cache.db-shm
/Users/USER/Library/Caches/com.dashlane.DashlanePluginService/Cache.db
/Users/USER/Library/Caches/com.dashlane.DashlanePluginService/Cache.db-wal
/Users/USER/Library/Caches/com.dashlane.DashlanePluginService/Cache.db-shm
```

#### master password

> Your master password is your private key to unlocking Dashlane. No one knows it but you, not even Dashlane, and it’s not stored anywhere on your computer or our servers.

<sup>Source: [Dashlane Security](https://www.dashlane.com/security)</sup>

> All essential user data is encrypted using AES-256 with a
>   key that derives from the user’s master password, and neither the master
>   password nor the key is stored locally or on Dashlane’s servers. As a result, the security of AES ensures that it is infeasible to obtain a user’s sensitive information without knowledge of their master password.

<sup>Source: [Security Analysis of Dashlane (May 2016)](https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.857/2016/files/25.pdf)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

They are stored locally in an encrypted vault on your device. Passwords are NOT stored online anywhere, neither is your master password.

You authenticate locally to the vault.

Answer (score 1):

On OSX, as of the date of this post, all the files are located in:

`~/Library/Application Support/Dashlane`

I had to restore those files the other day using time-machine and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

#### Where does Dashlane store it's password file/files?

They are stored online.

> Securely store your payment types in Dashlane’s online wallet. Get express checkout and flawless form filling everywhere you shop online.
>
> Automatically capture receipts of all your purchases. Always have your digital wallet on you, and never have to store your credit cards on sites that you don't completely trust.

Source [The only secure digital wallet
that’s universally accepted](https://www.dashlane.com/digitalwallet)

Answer (score 0):

I recently reinstalled my Windows OS to another drive and lost boot access to it. I only had the files available so I wanted to include the Dashlane database store location here for anyone looking for it on Windows.

### Password data files on Windows

```
%APPDATA%\Dashlane\profiles
```

On my machine this was:

```
C:\Users\foobar\AppData\Roaming\Dashlane\profiles
```

Just copy the profiles folder content from the old location to the new one and launch the Dashlane desktop app. You should have all your passwords and other data back at that point.